# Generar tuplas fijas por cada tupla de un resultado

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo 3 tablas: `areas`, `roles` y `personas`. Genero una jerarquía en base a ellas donde las `personas` cuelgan de su rol, cada rol cuelga de su `area`, y todas las áreas de una tupla fija. La consulta básica que dejo como ejemplo sería:

```
SELECT 'U' AS ID, NULL AS ID_PADRE, 'PADRE DE TODOS' AS DESCRIPCION FROM DUAL

UNION ALL 

SELECT ('A_' || ID_AREA) AS ID, 'U' AS ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION_AREA AS DESCRIPCION FROM AREAS

UNION ALL

SELECT ('R_' || ID_ROL) AS ID, ('A_' || ID_AREA_ROL) AS ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION_ROL AS DESCRIPCION FROM ROLES R

UNION ALL

SELECT ('P_' || ID_PERSONA) AS ID, ('R_' || ID_ROL_PERSONA) AS ID_PADRE, NOMBRE AS DESCRIPCION FROM PERSONA
```

Y me genera una jerarquía de este tipo (no se ven las personas, pero colgarían de cada uno de los roles que hay abajo de todo, como "*Chofer*", "*Enfermero*", etc):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que se me presenta ahora es: algunos trabajadores tienen `NULL` como `ID_ROL_PERSONA`, es decir, no tienen padre y no quiero dejarlos afuera, por lo que me gustaría poder generar una tupla del tipo:

```
SELECT ('ROL_NULO_' || ID_AREA_ROL) AS ID, ('A_' || ID_AREA_ROL) AS ID_PADRE, 'Sin rol!' AS DESCRIPCION FROM ANDA_A_SABER_DE_DONDE
```

Para cada área para poder tener a todos los de un área específica sin rol asignado en un mismo nodo llamado `Sin rol`.

¿Como puedo generar tantas tuplas `Sin rol` para cada área con SQL?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Estaría bueno que el que puso voto negativo explique por qué....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné cambiando:

```
SELECT ('P_' || ID_PERSONA) AS ID, ('R_' || ID_ROL_PERSONA) AS ID_PADRE, NOMBRE AS DESCRIPCION FROM PERSONA
```

Por:

```
SELECT ('P_' || ID_PERSONA) AS ID, ('R_' || ID_ROL_PERSONA) AS ID_PADRE, NOMBRE AS DESCRIPCION FROM PERSONA
WHERE ID_ROL_PERSONA IS NOT NULL
```

Y agregué las siguientes dos consultas:

```
-- Los "Sin roles para cada area"
SELECT ('RN_' || ID_AREA_PERSONA) AS ID, ('A_' || ID_AREA_PERSONA) AS ID_PADRE, "Sin rol" AS DESCRIPCION FROM PERSONA
WHERE ID_ROL_PERSONA IS NULL
GROUP BY ID_AREA_PERSONA

-- Los trabajadores sin roles
SELECT ('P_' || ID_PERSONA) AS ID, ('RN_' || ID_AREA_PERSONA) AS ID_PADRE, NOMBRE AS DESCRIPCION FROM PERSONA
WHERE ID_ROL_PERSONA IS NULL
```